# php unidentified index when calling function

Tags: php

Hi I am calling a function to upload an image to a MySQL database
but it keeps saying unidentified index image

I am uploading the image using this button

```
<input type="file" name="image" size="25" />
<input type ="submit" name = "Register_Btn" value ="Register">
```

which calls this

```
if(isset($_POST['Register_Btn'])){
    uploadImage($link);
    register($link);
}
```

then in pictureupload.php I have this function

```
<?php
function UploadImage($link){
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `authentication` ( `image_name`,`image`) VALUES ('{$image_name}','{$image}')";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }else{
        echo'No File Chosen';
    }   
}
```

?>

Every time ['image'] is used it is returning the 
Undefined index: image error and also
also on line 4 of the pictureupload it is also saying
file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
How do I ensure that it is receiving the uploaded image data?

Comment: have you print $_FILES array and checked you are getting image data or not ?

Comment: `//SQL Injection defence!`. Nope.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your image is really uploaded or not

```
<?php
function UploadImage($link){
if(isset($_FILES['image']) &&!empty($_FILES['image'])){// check file is uploaded or not
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `authentication` ( `image_name`,`image`) VALUES ('{$image_name}','{$image}')";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    }
}else{
        echo'No File Chosen';
    }   
}
```

Comment: hmmm yeah its not actually uploading any idea what could be the cause of that?

Comment: i mean the image name apears when i press upload so part of it is working

Answer (score 0):

ahha

forgot to include

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```